# R- ploting data with a long tail

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am a beginner in R. I want to do a simple plotting. I have a dataset with 2 columns which is extracted from a twitter dataset: "followers" which shows the number of followers a user has, and "count" which shows how many users have that many followers. I am trying to plot this dataset. The best plotting I could come up with so far is:

```
p<-ggplot(df, aes(x=df$user_followersCount, y= df$x )) +
geom_area(alpha=0.6) +
scale_x_continuous(name="Followers", limits=c(0, 30000000)) +
scale_y_continuous(name="Count") +
scale_x_sqrt()
```

Which gives me the following plot:
[image: Followers-Count Plot]

Because of the long tail, the plot is not good. I want the first 1000 followers to be shown on a bigger scale and the tail to be compressed. But I don't know how. Please help me.
Or maybe you have a suggestion to plot this data in a better way?

Comment: Yes, the answer is to plot log(data +1) instead of plotting the raw data.

Comment: Please post a representative sample of your data, preferably the output of `dput`

Comment: Also, using `dataframe$column` inside `ggplot` functions can lead to errors; instead it just expects the bare column names

Answer (score 1):

```
#Create some data
t <- append(rnorm(100000,0,1), rnorm(100,50,10))

#Plot with no log
hist(t)
```

[image]

```
   #Now lets try using log
   hist(log2(t+1))
```

[image]

This is a common technique for data visualization.

Comment: *"This is a common technique for "normalizing" the data."* Please note that this has nothing to do with data normalisation! It's a special case of a log-transformation of your data.

Comment: The base of the log is somewhat arbitrary, personally I find `log10` to be more human interpratable.